# nested includes in .net core 1.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have three models in .net core 1.1 MVC.

1. Communications

   ```
   public class Communication
   {
       public Guid CommunicationId { get; set; }
       public string Subject { get; set; }
       public bool IsRead { get; set; } = false;
       public Guid UserId { get; set; }
       public Guid AssignedTo { get; set; }
       public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
       public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
       public Nullable<DateTime> DeletedAt { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages {get; set;}
   }
   ```
2. Messages

   ```
   public class Message
   {
       public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
       public Guid CommunicationId { get; set; }
       public Guid SenderId { get; set; } = new Guid();
       public Guid ReceiverId { get; set; } = new Guid();
       public string Body { get; set; }
       public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
       public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
       public Nullable<DateTime> DeletedAt { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Users

SenderID and ReceiverID in Messages table is UserID in Users table.

Relation between these models:
Communications has_many Messages.
Message belongs_to a communication
Message belongs_to a user via SenderID
Message blongs_to a user via ReceiverId

Here is my controller looks like:

```
_context.Communications.Include(c=> c.Messages)
```

I want to generate a JSON object like this:
{communicationId: 'xxx', messages[{messageId: 'xxx', sender:{user info goes here}, receiver:{user info goes here} }

How do I include User object into Message object?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Add two properties of type Users to the Message table and use these to define your relationships on the SenderId and ReceiverId respectively to the Users table.

```
public virtual Users Sender { get; set; }
public virtual Users Receiver { get; set; }
```

Then change your query like this

```
_context.Communications.Include(c => c.Messages).Include("Message.Users");
```

Comment: Hi Morgan. one more question. How can I find all the communications for a given user?

e.g. My message has a senderId and ReceiverId. 

var communications = await _context.Communications.Include(c => c.Messages)
                .Where(m => m.Messages.senderId == id || m.Messages.ReceiverId == id).ToListAsync();

This is not the right syntax. what it should be? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use `ThenInclude`?

Comment: I believe ThenInclude is not the right solution for my problem. Messages is an icollection. I need a way to query icollection object

Comment: Hi Ajit. I am not sure i understand the last question. However i'll try to answer based on the same code you've posted in the comment. If you have a userId and you want to get all communications based on either SenderId or ReceiverId respectively, then the sample code you wrote should work just fine. Did you try running it? Did you get any errors? Let me know so i can help. 
Note: if the answer solved your first question, please mark it as a right answer.